# regarding wrapping a command line into a python script or function

Tags: command-line, python, command, python-3.x

in the command prompt, I can use `nvcc --version` to check the CUDA information. Is that possible to wrap this command `nvcc --version` into a python script to be run by python. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose for simple cases like yours, you can use Python function `os.system` although it has been deprecated.

Official Python documentation wants you to use the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) instead. See also [PEP324](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/).

Let me add that Stackoverflow and other forums have plenty of discussions about the merits and demerits of executing programs from Python in the first place, and which function to use.

Comment: `os.system` can be replicated using `subprocess.run(cmd,shell=True)` and subprocess has more features. Of course, just `subprocess.run(["nvcc","--version"])` would work here since a shell isn't needed.